# How to remove first line indentation in org-mode, in the editor?

Tags: org-mode

In org, whenever I create a new tree and make a new line, the editor automatically indents only this first line (different behavior of older versions).

I'd like the editor to behave so that it does not automatically indent that first line.

I have `org-indent-mode` disabled.

***Note from author:** this question was extract from: [How to remove first line indentation in org-mode, in the editor? #3872](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/3872) made by @leonkis (Github). The reason why I put it here was because it was hard to find. Also, I copied the answer from @hlissner (Github) from here: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/3872#issuecomment-684176505*

***2nd note:** This behavior changed in [Emacs 24.4, as you can see here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs24.4_features.html).*

Answer (score 2):

Unless you meant this occurs when you press RET on a new line. In which case, that's `electric-indent-mode`.

```
(electric-indent-mode -1) ; globally
;; or
(add-hook! 'org-mode-hook (electric-indent-local-mode -1))
```

*From: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/3872#issuecomment-684176505 by @hlissner (Github).*